# using rounded corners on galleryview plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, rounded-corners, photo-gallery

I have a jquery galleryview plugin running to display photos. i would like to add rounded corners to the photos, so i tried applying the corners plugin to the .panel holding the image. unfortunately it doesnt work. the photo starts square and then when it transitions you can see the rounding for a second and then it ends square again.

any thoughts on how to go about this would be appreciated.
the site is in production at www.dnbsandox.com/caliaq/
you can see that corners.js plugin is working on the box holding the gallery (div#photos).

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use the rounded corners.js you can do this with css,

```
div#photos{
-moz-border-radius: 5px; //mozilla
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; //safari
}
```

Comment: well... no, the css is overwritten by the inline style applied by the gallery plugin. and without the corner plugin ie wont display rounded corners... but that is less of an issue. if i could do it with the strait css that would be fine, but it doesnt work. i even tried adding it into the gallery script, but i think i am not adding it in the right place.